# how to convert a string array to number array?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am trying to convert a string array to a number array
A quick google search have lead me to this solution.

```
    let numbersAsStringArray = originalQueryParams[property] ?? []
    let numbers = numbersAsStringArray.map((i) => Number(i));
```

where I keep getting this i

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'.
```

numbersAsStringArray is just an simple array with a number in as a string.

Comment: It seems the type of `originalQueryParams[property]` is not an array or at least typescript is not sure about it. You need to cast if you are sure it is an array or use a type guard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a compilation error, not runtime error. Just tell TS that numberAsStringArray is of type `string[]` and it should be ok.

```
let numbersAsStringArray = (originalQueryParams[property] || []) as string[];
let numbers = numbersAsStringArray.map((i) => Number(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `let numbers = Array.from(numbersAsStringArray,Number)`